# Where to find good Windows-compatible mouse cursor images?

Tags: cursor, cursors

I"d like to find some good, basic mouse cursor graphics (like the pointing finger used when mousing over a hyperlink).

Any suggestions of some good sources for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Open Cursor Library](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-library). Comes with a preview of each cursor.

Comment: Nice. It's searchable by keyword. "pointing finger" only got me *middle* finger cursors, but "hand" got me some good ones.

Comment: Glad to help. I like the previews though, beats downloading a whole bunch of them based on descriptions.